# How do i repair a corrupt drive without losing data

Tags: partition, nas, guid

I was copying data from an old ds112 Synology hard drive to a new install on a  ds112 due to board failure of the other one. I have the old drive in a caddy and was successfully copying data when I had a power failure. When trying to restart the copying I get the following errors when using extFS for Mac:

```
Error while iterating over blocks in inode 6356: input/output error
Either the superblock or the partition is likely to be corrupt
```

I have these errors in Terminal:

```
Unable to verify this whole disk: A Guid Partition Table (GPT) partitioning scheme is required (-697773)
```

I don't have a clue what I am doing. I'm trying not to destroy the data.

```
MacM:~ root# sudo diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *320.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            319.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *124.2 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data ex128gb                 123.9 GB   disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                      Linux                         2.6 GB     disk2s1
   2:                 Linux_Swap                         2.1 GB     disk2s2
   3:                      Linux                         2.0 TB     disk2s3
```

**Some details about the disk**

```
MacM:~ root# sudo diskutil info disk2
   Device Identifier:        disk2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk2
   Whole:                    Yes
   Part of Whole:            disk2
   Device / Media Name:      UITRA1

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      FDisk_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported

   Disk Size:                2.0 TB (2000398934016 Bytes) (exactly 3907029168 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:          External
   Removable Media:          Fixed

   Virtual:                  No

MacM:~ root# sudo diskutil repairDisk disk2
Unable to repair this whole disk: A GUID Partition Table (GPT) partitioning scheme is required (-69773)
MacM:~ root# sudo gpt show disk2
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1         255         
         256     4980480      1  MBR part 131
     4980736     4194304      2  MBR part 130
     9175040      262144         
     9437184  3897586881      3  MBR part 131
  3907024065        5103
```

UPDATE:

extFS for mac is software by paragon. i have the software on my mac trying to recover software from a nas file server, the power went during a successful copy when i had the old nas drive in a caddy plugged into my new nas file server. when i tried to restart, the new nas drive would not recognise the usb caddy and kept throwing an i/o error.

plugged back into my mac to use the extFS software and now i am getting the above errors

just to reiterate i have no idea what i am doing. i am not technical. all i know it was working, my new nas box was recognising the usb drive and i was copying the data across. The extFS software could read the drive.

power cut = nothing is able to read the drive - errors stated above.

Comment: What kind of recovery software are you using? Also, can you run `diskutil list` and copy/paste the part relating to the disk in question into your question?

Comment: done that but its not very readable, sorry

Comment: Which ExtFS enabler are you using? Often they do not allow repair, nor hand on repair capability to the Mac's own structures. [Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/) claims to, but I haven't used it.

Comment: thanks but i have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: The best way to avoid loosing data due to a corrupt drive is to go to your backup.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion, i'd of never of thought of going to a backup. can anyone suggest any help with my original question?

Comment: *"errors when using extFS for Mac:"* …which one? ExtFS is not native to Mac, so diskutil will not fix ExtFS drives. You need to use the software you added to enable ExtFS.

Comment: which one? both.

Comment: more explanation added above

Comment: do i need to plug the drive into a linux operating system?

Comment: You say "successful copy". So have you successfully copied all the data to the new drive, or not? I'm guessing from your reply to Solar Mike that you don't have a backup. Because the Synology NAS uses non-native file-systems, you can't fix this easily on MacOS. I would ask Synology what software they recommend for repairing their disks.

Comment: thanks for that useful reply, i will ask them now, i already have a support ticket open.

by successful copy, i mean my new nas recognised the usb nas and allowed me to start copying the data from the usb nas to the new nas, then the power cut.

i'm badly trying to highlight that the usb nas was working fine before the power cut, now its throwing the errors.

Comment: "which one? both" makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.  If you are using Paragon, then that's what you need to use to attempt repairs. Terminal commands are not going to do it, because the Mac still doesn't know how to deal with ExtFS repairs. Look at the Paragon manual.

Comment: by both i mean when i scroll up the error window both errors are present in the feed. The paragon software fails the repair, throwing the error: Error while iterating over blocks in inode 6356: input/output error; then when i scroll up i see the error: Either the superblock or the partition is likely to be corrupt.

Comment: If Paragon can't fix it, then you'd probably need to try it on something native, a nix distro of some sort… otherwise it's back to the backup. Mac can't handle ExtFS itself.

Comment: i give up on here, ive moved to another forum. not sure why i am getting the answers i am after the info i have put.Pretty sure if i had a back up i wouldnt be here...

Comment: Well, your answers to questions were at best terse, at worst confusing. I asked you which ExtFS app you use, you answered "both". The more info we get from you, the better the answers can be. Getting annoyed at people trying to help you makes them not want to help you. SO… good luck. I'm out. Of course if you had a backup you wouldn't be here. ***That's what backups are for.*** They are those things you really don't need until you really need them… then there's no substitute.